# Rails gem Ransack -> search 'or condition' with 'is null' and a specific value (field=x OR field IS NULL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, ransack

I made a support ticket system for our supporters - programmed with ruby on rails (Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.2)

There is a ticket model with a `belongs_to` association to users (supporter).

I use Ernie's gem Ransack for searching.
When the supporter searches his own tickets (handled by tickets_controller.index) he should also see the unassociated tickets in the search result (views/tickets/index) (in combination with the other serach conditions eg. "date" or something else)

(So that he can take an open ticket)

expected SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ... AND (user_id=5 OR user_id IS NULL) AND ...
```

I tried `user_id_null_or_user_id_eq` in the search form of the index-view - but that does not work (no method error)

How can I make a custom predicate (or ransacker) to solve this problem? (Thanks @Magnuss for this comment)

Unfortunately, I have no experience with Arel

Something like:

```
ransacker :user_null_or_eq do
    ...
end
```

in the tickets model.

I hope this explains the problem in more detail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've provided enough info to help.

Comment: It doesn't seem like Ransack will let you do `null_or` query. You'll have to create your own predicate (ransacker ?).

Comment: @Beerlington - I tried to explain the problem in more detail

Answer (score 6):

I also had to figure this out and @TomG answer helped a lot! 
You really don't need to create a ransacker for this issue, it an be fixed by using the build_grouping method of ransack (that is not documented anywhere...) and put in the condition you need with 'or' condition.

I used it to search items to add to a cage but wanted to show the user only items that are not already in my cage (and also not assigned to any other cage), so in my controller:

```
   @search = Cage.ransack(params[:q])
   @search.build_grouping({:m => 'or', :storage_id_not_eq => @cage_item.id, :storage_id_null => true})  
   @results_count = @search.result(:distinct => true).length
   @items = @search.result(:distinct => true).paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page] || 1)

   @search.build_condition if @search.conditions.empty?
   @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?
```

So when I'm printing the query ransack is running it will show:

```
 @search.result.to_sql
"SELECT `specimens`.* FROM `specimens`  WHERE (`specimens`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND ((`specimens`.`storage_id` != 183 OR `specimens`.`storage_id` IS NULL))"
```

and if I add a name query:

```
@search.result.to_sql
"SELECT `specimens`.* FROM `specimens`  WHERE (`specimens`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND ((`specimens`.`name` LIKE '%root%' AND (`specimens`.`storage_id` != 183 OR `specimens`.`storage_id` IS NULL)))"
```

Hope this helps you or someone else with having trouble using OR in ransack conditions instead of the basic AND.

Answer (score 1):

OK - here is my own solution - inspired by graywh (thank you very much): [ransack/issues/290](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/290)

You can add a new grouping node -with an 'or'-combinator- to the ransack object.

In index view I changed `f.select :user_id_eq` to `select_tag ...`

tickets_controller.index:

```
@q = Ticket.search(params[:q])  
if params[:user_id_eq] && params[:user_id_eq]!=''  
  @q.build_grouping({:m => 'or', :user_id_eq => params[:user_id_eq], :user_id_null => true})  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build your query params like this

```
q: {g: [ {m: 'or', user_id_eq: 5, user_id_null: 1} ] }
```

where this:

```
user_id_null: 1
```

is only flag to search for null value